# How can I select complete <li> element in navigation bar when hovered or selected?

Tags: html, css, uinavigationbar

This is how I want the navigation bar, as in : http://themediaoctopus.com/social-media/nostalgic-approach-advertising

How to change the complete color of `<li>` when hovered on or selected?
Any idea on how to get those seperators between those buttons?

Selection action doesn't work, why? I'm on a particular page and that button on navigation bar is not highlighted. Why and how can I do it?

Here is my current navigation bar when hovered:

[image]

**Here is my HTML :**

```
<body>
    <nav>
         <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
          <li><a href="how_it_works.html">HOW IT WORKS</a></li>
          <li><a href="get_it.html">GET IT</a></li>
          <li><a href="what_you_can_do.html">WHAT YOU CAN DO</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>     
         </ul>
      </nav>
</body>
```

**Here is my CSS :**

```
body {
    color : #F9F9F9;
}
nav {
    background-color: #26AD60;
    margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
}
nav ul {
    margin: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
}
nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}
nav ul li a:link, nav ul li a:visited {
    color: #F9F9F9;
    border-bottom: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li a:active {
    background-color: #1C8148;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #1C8148;
    color: #F9F9F9;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: You won't be able to select the active page (e.g. highlighting the nav element of the page you are viewing) without some kind of dynamic component of the code.  Pure HTML/CSS does not know or care what page you are on.  Use JS to test for which page you're on and add an "active" class to the `li` of the page you're on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its good if you use **a:hover** and the properties given to it... which allow user to have clickable area been selected and highlighted.

```
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">project</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
    nav{
        display:block;
        background:#26AD60;
    }
    nav ul{
        list-style:none;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    nav ul li{
        float:left;
        border-right: 1px dashed rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);    
    }
    nav ul li:last-child{
        border:none;
    }
    nav ul li a{
        transition: all 0.25s linear 0s;
       padding: 0px 20px;
       line-height: 50px;
       outline: medium none;
       font-family:arial;
       font-size:12px;
       color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
       text-shadow: none;
       text-transform: uppercase;
       text-decoration:none;
       display:block;
    }
    nav ul li a:hover{
       background: #229b56;
    }
```

Please check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cooolkiran/NT563/) to see the same.

Comment: Wow! Thats really wonderful! But can u give some more info on transitions buddy, that would help me a lot.Thanks for ur time!Thats really invaluable work.

Comment: @nikhil to know more about css transition Please follow the link which explains you with the examples :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions.

Comment: Thanks @Kiran , Can I use a different font instead Arial, I changed it but no effect.Why is color important as u mentioned.

Comment: @nikhil i will do some changes to the css which will be easy for you to use.. well **important** was by mistake i will remove that. :)

Answer (score 3):

Add this:

```
padding: 15px 10px 15px 10px;
```

To your `nav ul li:hover{` CSS

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/39Lzp/

In order to have that item be highlighted based on the page you are on you can add a class to it and style that class accordingly. Then, in each different HTML file, you add that class to the corresponding element. For example, `index.html` would look like this:

```
<li class="current"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="how_it_works.html">HOW IT WORKS</a></li>
```

But `how_it_works.html` would look like this:

```
<li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
<li class="current"><a href="how_it_works.html">HOW IT WORKS</a></li>
```

Now, for the borders, all you need to do is use the `border` property like so:

```
nav ul li {
    border-left: 1px dashed white;
}
nav ul li:first-of-type {
    border-left: none;
}
```

Also, in order for the border to span the entire height of the nav bar, change this:

```
nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}
```

To this:

```
nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 15px 10px 15px 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LbBEK/

Also, for future reference, you have 3 separate questions here. Next time, break your questions up to be more concise and you'll find yourself getting a much better response here on SO.

Comment: It worked @Dryden Long.Cool! Thanks! Can you help me with getting those white seperators as in the link I mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: Thats invaluable stuff buddy! Thanks a ton! I'll definitely follow the last suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `hover` statement background-color

```
nav ul li:hover { 
    background-color: blue; // here
    color: #F9F9F9;;
}
```

You may want to change the `active` statement too

```
nav ul li a:active {
    background-color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

For the border, you can like something like this :

```
nav ul li {
    border-right: 1px dashed rgba(255,255,255,0.25)
}

nav ul li:last-child {
   border: 0; // they dont do this, but I prefer with it. As you want.
}
```

[Demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aloisdg/4wYc2/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Apply this on hover  `padding: 15px 10px 15px 0px;`

[***See demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/sJ5rG/)

Apply border property `border-right: 1px dashed #fff` for dashed separation between `li`.